# Manipulating map/list in javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

a brief explanation of my problem: I have an apex class that invoke a server to get a result in this form `Map<String1, List<Map<String2,String3>>>`
So using the content of this result I would like to use javascript to create two dependent picklists. In the first one i would like to put all the String1 and in the second the String2 corresponding to the right String1.

I have already made this using a method that generate a selectList and that puts the String1 values in selectOptions .. but this is not the best way to do that so can someone tell me what's the best way to do that without invoking the server.. ?? I don't know if it's possible to manipulate Map and List objects with javascript so if you have examples I'd be more than grateful!

```
        strings1 = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        Set<String> keys = result.keySet();
        for (String str: keys) {
                strings1.add(new SelectOption(str, str));
        }
```

this is the way i create the first picklist.

```
public List<SelectOption> strings2(){
    strings2 = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(item1 != null){
        List<Map<String,String>> str2_str3 = result.get(); 
        if(str2_str3.size() > 0){
            for(Integer i=0; i < str2_str3.size(); i++){
                Set<String> key = str2_str3[i].keySet();
                for(String str2:key){
                    strings2.add(new SelectOption(str2,str2));
                }
            }
        } 
        return str2;    
    }
    else{
        return strings2;
    }
}   
else{
        strings2.add(new SelectOption('','- no "String1" selected -'));
        return strings2;
    }
}
```

and this is how i create the second picklist

Comment: It is possible to manipulate `Map` and `List` types in JavaScript, they're represented as `JSON objects { key: value }` and `Arrays`, respectively. Show us the code you've written and maybe we can help get you to a solution.

Comment: i've added my code in the question.
thanks for you answer